# Interpret PHP inside a quote in a PHP

Tags: php, html

I have this variable `$url` that I need to print inside a quoted HTML that it's inside a PHP if conditional.

```
<?php 
$url = $thumb['0']; 
if ( in_category( 'News' )) {
    //nothing here
} else {
    echo '<div class="image-holder"><img src="$url;" alt="Post photo" class="image-border"></div>';
}
?>
```

But `src="$url;"` is interpreted as `src="$url;"` in the HTML code. It does not interpret as a variable.

How can I solve that?

Comment: use double quotes " instead of single ' around string

Comment: When i use double quotes the page breaks (everything turns white)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like to seperate the business logic from the output. This, in combination with [PHP's alternative syntax for control structures](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php), keeps your HTML output clean and easily readable.

See this example:

```
<?php
// Do some things here
$url = $thumb['0'];

// Below this point we output HTML
// Only use simple control structures here, this keeps your HTML clean and easy to read
?>

<?php if (in_category('News')): ?>

<?php else: ?>
<div class="image-holder"><img src="<?php echo $url; ?>" alt="Post photo" class="image-border">
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Since the first part of the if-statement is empty, you can simplify the code:

```
<?php if (!in_category('News')): ?>
<div class="image-holder"><img src="<?php echo $url; ?>" alt="Post photo" class="image-border">
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

you can concatenate strings with a dot in php

e.g

```
echo "This"."is"."a"."sample";
```

likewise with variables:

```
    echo '<div class="image-holder"><img src="'.$url.'" alt="Post photo" class="image-border"></div>';
```

Answer (score 2):

When working with strings in PHP, it's important to realize the distinction between single- and double-quoted strings.

- [Single-quoted strings](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single) are basically parsed as literal strings, regardless of what 'special' characters you might use.  The only escape sequences are `\'` for a literal single quote and `\\` for a literal backslash. PHP code is treated as simple text, and so are escape sequences like `\n` (the sequence for a unix newline). This is the format to use for simple string literals like 'Hello World!'.
- [Double-quoted strings](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double) are parsed completely, meaning `\n` is interpreted as a newline and `$var` is replaced with the value of the variable `$var`. So this is much more powerful, but you also have to think more about how your strings will be interpreted. If your interpreted php gets complicated (or is adjacent to non-php that might look like php), you can [use braces](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.complex) to clarify your meaning.

Note that there are lots of reasons not to mix strings with php code. Often [`sprintf`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php), [heredoc](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc), or simple concatenation (with `.`) make things much clearer, as suggested in several other answers.

Answer (score 0):

Use double quotes and surround your variable in curley braces example

```
echo "This is my variable. It equals {$var}";
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this

```
echo '<div class="image-holder"><img src="'.$url.'" alt="Post photo" class="image-border"></div>';
```

or

```
echo "<div class='image-holder'><img src='$url' alt='Post photo' class='image-border'></div>";
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to work with large portions of HTML and don't want to have to change from double to single quotes [technically disallowed by HTML spec], or escape all of the double quotes [pain in the butt], or constantly drop in and out of `<?php ?>` tags [ugly, hard to maintain], then use a [HEREDOC](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc). eg:

```
echo <<<_end_
<div class="image-holder"><img src="$url;" alt="Post photo" class="image-border"></div>
_end_;
```

Variables are expanded, no quotes need escaping, and all of your dreams will come true.

Alternatively, you can stick with a single-quoted string and get cozy with [`printf()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.printf.php) which is a fantastically useful function in its own right. eg:

```
printf('<div class="image-holder"><img src="%s;" alt="Post photo" class="image-border"></div>', $url);
```

Answer (score -1):

Do this, (EDIT: simplified code)

```
<?php 
$url = $thumb['0']; 
if ( ! in_category( 'News' ) ) {?>
    <div class="image-holder">
       <img src="<?=$url?>" alt="Post photo" class="image-border" />
    </div>
<?}?>
```